# CRM Reports not getting executed for more than 20 records

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

When I executed reports in CRM 2011 by selecting more than 20 records it give the following error:

> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: An error has
>   occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) --->
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: Query execution
>   failed for dataset 'DsPhoneCallBase'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

This is happening for both system reports and custom reports.

Answer (score 3):

When you review the SSRS log you might find this error.

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object
>   ‘fn_GetGuidsFromString’, database ‘MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM’, schema ‘dbo’.

If so then this is a known issue supposedly fixed in UR8. You will find reference to it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/04/20/podcast-and-overview-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-update-rollup-8.aspx

See this blog for a work around until you upgrade.

http://xrm4you.wordpress.com/tag/support/

Answer (score 0):

If possible, attach a SQL Server Profiler to the database server and make sure to include  "Events: Error" in the events selection. This will show you which statement fails and why.

You might also be able to find pointer in the reporting services log files:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.x\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```